# Google calendar API create events with Meet

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create an event on a calendar with an associated Meet link with `googleapis` library for nodejs.

I tried with this payload:

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-09-04T20:39:01.000Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-09-04T20:38:01.000Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
  },
  "conferenceData": {
    "createRequest": {
      "requestId": "7qxalsvy0e"
    }
  }
}
```

And with this one:

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-09-04T20:39:01.000Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-09-04T20:38:01.000Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
  },
  "conferenceData": {
    "conferenceSolution": {
      "key": {
        "type": "hangoutsMeet"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It succesfully creates the event on my calendar but without the meet link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about your actual script, from `It succesfully creates the event on my calendar but without the meet link`, I'm worried that `conferenceDataVersion` might not be added to the query parameter. If this is reflected in a sample script using your request body, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth }); // Please use your client.
const calendarId = "###";

const resource = {
  end: {
    dateTime: "2023-09-04T20:39:01.000Z",
    timeZone: "Europe/London",
  },
  start: {
    dateTime: "2023-09-04T20:38:01.000Z",
    timeZone: "Europe/London",
  },
  conferenceData: {
    createRequest: {
      requestId: "7qxalsvy0e",
      conferenceSolutionKey: { type: "hangoutsMeet" },
    },
  },
  summary: "sample event title",
};

calendar.events.insert({ calendarId, resource, conferenceDataVersion: 1 })
  .then(({ data }) => console.log(data))
  .catch(({ errors }) => console.log(errors));
```

- When this script is run, a new event is created with the Meet link.

#### Reference:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

Comment: requestId: "7qxalsvy0e" - Is that any random string? Or is something sacrosanct about this string?

Comment: @Vikas About your question of `requestId: "7qxalsvy0e" - Is that any random string? Or is something sacrosanct about this string?`, the official document says `The client-generated unique ID for this request. Clients should regenerate this ID for every new request. If an ID provided is the same as for the previous request, the request is ignored.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) For example, when the same request ID is not used, a value of `abc` can be also used.